# Use journey entry data for personalization in email

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I want to create an email that contains a personalized URL based on an email address. I am using the Journey Builder and the entry source is Salesforce data.

I can see that the email adress and name of the contacted person are part of the entry source:

[image: Data entry source for journey]

However, when I try to use the email value in the email that is the next node in the journey, the previous StackExchange answers don't work. I've tried
[Contact:Email], and AttributeValue("Contact:Email").

The first option [Contact:Email] throws an error in validation:

```
There is an error in your email. Please contact your customer service representative. Fehler 1: Script SET Statement Invalid<br>An error occurred when attempting to resolve a script expression. See inner exception for detail. Script Expression: [Contact:Email] MemberID: XXXX JobID: 0 An unrecognized expression appears in a script block. Script Expression: [Contact:Email] MemberID: XXXX JobID: 0 <br>Ungültiger Inhalt: <br>SET @email2 = [Contact:Email]).
```

The second version using AttributeValue doesn't throw an error, but the value is not populated in the email that is sent out.

I set the variable like this in the email:

```
%%[set @email = AttributeValue("Contact:Email")]%%

 Guten Tag %%=v(@email)=%%,
```

and the email arrives like this:

[image: Guten Tag without email value populated]

The email value was not retrieved. How can I retrieve the email value?

The field name in the journey data extension is also seemingly called Contact:Email:
[image: Journey data extension]

Comment: what is the field called in the DE?

Comment: It is also apparently called Contact:Email. I added a screenshot of the data extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that Contact is your root, and you're attempting to retrieve the email address field from that object, the easiest method for retrieving this would be:

```
%%[
 set @email = emailaddr
]%%
```

This will populate the variable `email` with the email address that you are deploying the email to. Additionally, you could use the bracket syntax (i.e. `[Contract:Email]`) if you'd prefer an alternative and want to retrieve this directly from the source DE.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, the email is not filled out, neither with
AttributeValue('emailaddr')
nor with 
AttributeValue('Contact:Email')

Comment: It's not possible to send an email and not have access to the emailaddr personalization string.

Comment: You are right. The error was fully on my side. I had set the variable in a "Text" field in Salesforce, which didn't work. When I put it in an HTML field, it worked. Duh. Thanks for your help.